# MS Access writing to Excel over multiple minutes will sometimes throw a false error

Tags: excel, ms-access, automation

I'm someone who solves problems by looking, not asking. So this is new to me. This has been an issue for years, and it crops up with different computers, networks, versions and completely different code. There is a lot here, so, thank you in advance if you are willing to read the whole thing. 
Generally speaking, I write MS Access programs that will open Excel and then create multiple worksheets inside of a workbook using data from Access tables and/or Excel sheets. The process can take a couple of minutes to run and occasionally, it will get an error. I could tell you the error message, but it doesn't matter because it will be different depending where the error occurs. When it occurs I simply click debug and click continue and it... continues. If it errors out again (many loops later), it will happen in the exact same spot.

So, what I start with is to make minor changes to the code. In the current program I'm working on, the error happens when I write to a cell and the value is a value directly from a table. I created a variable, copied the value to the variable and then wrote to the cell. The error moved to a completely different part of the program and it became a "paste" error. Generally what fixes it is to put a wait function at the spot where the error occurs. One second is usually good enough. Sometimes it takes a couple of these, but that usually solves it. It only took one delay per loop this time, so it is working. I just hate causing delays in my program. So... Has anyone seen anything like this before, or is it just me. It feels like a timing issue between Access and Excel since the delays are usually helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try decompiling your mdb ?

Comment: It's actually an accdb and no I didn't. That's an interesting idea. I might try it next time just to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe now this is a timing issue. After thinking things through, I realized that I could easily (well 3 hours later) separate the database info from the spreadsheet info and then move the updated code that is causing problems into an Excel Macro. I then called that macro from Access. Not only do the errors go away, but it runs about 4 times faster. It's not surprising, I just hadn't thought of that direction before.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up my last major Access project that interacted with Word (ca. 2016) where I struggled with similar issues. I see many, many `Debug.Print` statements (some commented, some still active), but unlike what I recalled earlier in my comments, I don't see any "wait" statements anymore! From what I now recall and after re-inspecting the code, most problems were resolved by

1. implementing robust error handling and best practices for always closing automation objects (and/or releasing the objects if I wanted the instances to persist)
2. subscribing to and utilizing appropriate automation object **events** to detect and handle interaction rather than trying to force everything into serialized work-then-wait code. To do this, I placed all automation code in well-structured classes that declared automation objects `WithEvents` (in VBA of course) and then defined relevant event handlers for actions I was effecting. I now recall finally being able to avoid weird errors and application hangs, etc.

---

You also may never get a good answer to a question like this, so despite that I am not an absolute expert on Office development, I have had my own experience with frustrating bugs like this and so I'll share my 2 cents.  This may not be satisfying, but after experiencing similar behavior using office automation objects, my general understanding is that interaction between OS processes are not deterministic.  Especially since VBA generally has no threading or parallelism concerns, it can be strange to deal with objects that behave in unpredictable ways.  The time slices given to each process separately is at the mercy of the OS and it will vary greatly with multiple processors/cores, running processes, memory management, etc.  Despite the purpose of the automation objects--to control instances of office apps--the API's are not designed well for inter-application processes.

Although it would be great if old automation code would produces more useful errors, perhaps nested exceptions (like in .Net and other modern environments), something that indicates delays and timeouts within callbacks between automation objects, instead you get hodgepodge of various context errors.

My hardware is old, but still ticking.  I often get delays, even if only for a second, when switching between apps, etc.  Instead of thinking of it as an error, I just perceive it as a slow machine, just wait and continue.  It may be useful to consider these type of random errors as similar delays.  If a wait call here or there resolves the issue, however annoying, that may just be the best solution... wait and continue.

Every now and then after debugging these types of issues I would actually discover the underlying problem and be able to fix it.  At the least I would be able to avoid actual problems with the data, despite errors being raised, just like you describe.  But even when I felt that I understood the problem, the answer was still often to do exactly as you have done and just add a short wait.

Comment: There is no guarantee that they work. Also, it might work on my computer, but maybe not on my clients. And they slow things down. In this latest program, it is going to cost me about 30 seconds in processing time. That's a lot of time when someone is waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Of course your end goal is to fix the problem and I'm sure you would appreciate someone responding who immediately has the magic answer, but really your question was very unspecific:  *"Has anyone seen anything like this before?"*  I answered that question.  If you really want a solution, I suggest that you ask a new question and **share relevant code**.  Show how you're instantiating and interacting with the Excel object.  Give at least a couple examples of errors.  Even though the errors change, **share the details anyway** if you want more than what I gave you. Otherwise it's all guesswork.

Comment: Updated my answer with perhaps more useful advice.

Comment: I appreciate all of the time you gave this question. I knew going in it was going to be hard to document. Showing the section of code where the error happened probably isn't relevant, which means showing the entire program is the only way for someone to really look at this. I have looked at making sure all objects are reset when I'm done using them, and it's possible that I missed something. It could also be the way I do the coding. Maybe my style of opening using Excel objects is problematic with longer processes. You've given me some great things to look at. Thank you.